# Primefaces , botão requer dois cliques para executar ação

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Ao executar o código abaixo, tenho que clicar duas vezes no botão para que a ação de exclusão aconteça vi muitos com problemas parecidos, mas nenhuma solução eficaz:

```
<h:form id="TablePais"  prependId="false" >
        <p:dataTable id="tbPais" var="pais" value="#{beanPais.listagem}"  emptyMessage="Não há registros">
            <p:column headerText="Ações">
                 <p:commandButton
                     id="deleteButton"
                     icon="ui-icon-trash"
                            actionListener="#{beanPais.excluir}"
                            update="tbPais"
                            ajax="false">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                value="#{pais}"
                                target="#{beanPais.selectedPais}"
                                />       
                    </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Codigo">
                <h:outputText value="#{pais.cod}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Nome:">
                <h:outputText value="#{pais.nome}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Eu tive o mesmo problema, o que eu tive que fazer foi colocar um `global="false"` no botão, pois assim ele não deixa o ajaxStatus ativar antes de sua ativação. No meu caso, o ajaxStatus estava atualizando um campo antes de executar o botão.

Answer (score 3):

Você está utilizando ajax=false juntamente com update, e isso é errado.

Update é para ser utilizado com ajax=true ou nem precisa escrever o atributo ajax.

Comment: tentei das duas formas e o problema persiste

Comment: Troque o update por 'TablePais'

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, poderia tentar utilizar o atributo `process="@this"` e `partialSubmit="true"`? caso o problema persista tente apenas para teste utilizar o procedimento conforme abaixo:

Altere seu método de excluir para receber um objeto de pais como parâmetro para realizar a exclusão.

```
    <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#
{beanPais.excluir(pais)}" update="tbPais" ajax="true" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" />
```

Metodo da classe BeanPais:

```
public void excluir(SeuObjetoPais pais){
   //... Procedimentos de exclusão levando em conta o parametro enviado.
}
```